# how to use a model from another controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Please help me to solve my problem:

I have resource pages:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @pages = Page.all
  end

  ...
end
```

And it also has a controller:

```
class PagesControlsController < PagesController
  def index
    @pages_controls = Pages.all
  end
end
```

The problem is that in the controller does not have access to the pages. Therefore I get the following error message:

> uninitialized constant PagesControlsController::Pages

Comment: `Pages.all` should be `Page.all` without `s`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just need to make `Pages` singular

Answer (score 1):

As per rails, table name should be plural and model name should be singular .for example pages table is mapped with Page model .
so in other controller you should write

```
@pages_controls = Page.all
```

which will fetch all data from pages table